# No such file or directory error when running program in anaconda prompt

Tags: python, excel, anaconda, command-prompt

I have been making a simple python script to practice reading in and writing to an excel file. I have a couple simple functions that create a dataframe from the excel file, allows the user to create a new row (i.e. updated savings balance etc.), then append the dataframe with the new row on the bottom and save it back to excel.

Basically every function begins with:`dfTest = pd.read_excel('FinancesExcel.xlsx', sheet_name='Test')`

and writes to with:

```py
    dfTestNew = dfTest.append(new_row,ignore_index=True)
    
    with pd.ExcelWriter('FinancesExcel.xlsx') as writer:
        dfTestNew.to_excel(writer, sheet_name='Test',index=False)
```

When I run it in Spyder it works great. Updates and saves no problem, as many times as you want before exiting.

When I try to run it in Anaconda Prompt it loads the main menu...

```py
    i = 0
    while i != 1:
    print("Main Menu")
    
    selection = input('1 - Quick Update\n'
                      '2 - Full Update\n'
                      '3 - Overview\n'
                      '4 - Visualize\n'
                      '5 - Forecast\n'
                      'Selection: ')
```

Currently only options 1-3 are built out but they all begin with: `dfTest = pd.read_excel('FinancesExcel.xlsx', sheet_name='Test')`

If you select any of the options 1-3 it yeilds...

Traceback (most recent call last):

```
  File "D:\Python\Projects\PersonalFinance\PersonalFinanceTest.py", line 273, in <module>
    dfTest = pd.read_excel('FinancesExcel.xlsx', sheet_name='Test')
  File "D:\michaData\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\excel\_base.py", line 304, in read_excel
    io = ExcelFile(io, engine=engine)
  File "D:\michaData\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\excel\_base.py", line 824, in __init__
    self._reader = self._engines[engine](self._io)
  File "D:\michaData\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\excel\_xlrd.py", line 21, in __init__
    super().__init__(filepath_or_buffer)
  File "D:\michaData\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\excel\_base.py", line 353, in __init__
    self.book = self.load_workbook(filepath_or_buffer)
  File "D:\michaData\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\excel\_xlrd.py", line 36, in load_workbook
    return open_workbook(filepath_or_buffer)
  File "D:\michaData\lib\site-packages\xlrd\__init__.py", line 111, in open_workbook
    with open(filename, "rb") as f:

FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'FinancesExcel.xlsx'

FinancesExcel.xlsx is definitely there, where it always is when it runs in Spyder. I don't have the file open when I run the script (already learned that lesson).
```

I am unable to figure out why it will not run.

Comment: Try using the absolute path to the file.

Answer (score 0):

check your current working directory when you are running the script in Anaconda Prompt:

```
import os

print(f'your current wd is: {os.getcwd()}')
```

I am confident that it is different than the one you are running from the Spyder. You need to provide the full path to your Excel file. "path/to/excel/FinancesExcel.xlsx"

Comment: I am unsure what to do with that. I entered in into the anaconda prompt window and it yielded...

>>> import os
>>> print(f'your current wd is: {os.gecwd()}')
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
AttributeError: module 'os' has no attribute 'gecwd'

I replaced all instances of 'FinancesExcel.xlsx' with the variable below and again it worked in spyder but not anaconda prompt.

filepath = 'D:\Python\Projects\PersonalFinance\FinancesExcel.xlsx'